# Expressions Web 4 Format Code Shortcut?

Tags: html, expression-web

Is there a keyboard shortcut for formatting code like Visual Studio has Ctrl+K Ctrl+D?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it.... http://expression-web-wiki.com/index.php?title=Format_code

Comment: Where is the shortcut in that document?

Answer (score 9):

Based on [@Ryan Anderson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3517193/117507):

To reformat the code of an existing page:

1. Open the web page you want to reformat.
2. In the Code pane, right-click and select Reformat HTML.